# How to get as much debug traffic information, as possible when using WWW::Scripter module in Perl?

Tags: javascript, perl, browser, mechanize, lwp

I am using `WWW::Scripter` module in my **Perl** application and I am trying to find out what exactly the code is doing, which pages/images/etc it downloads, what headers and contents it gets and in what order.

The code is something like this:

```
        #!/usr/bin/perl -w0
         
        use strict;
        use warnings;
        use LWP::Debug qw(+);
        use LWP::ConnCache;
        use WWW::Scripter;
         
        ...
         
        my $w = WWW::Scripter->new(agent => '...', autocheck => 1);
        $w->conn_cache(LWP::ConnCache->new); # keep alive
        $w->use_plugin('JavaScript');
         
        ...
         
        $w->get($url);
         
        ...
```

What do I need to do, to get some debug information as said above, headers and contents of each request, order of requests, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply [instrumentation](http://p3rl.org/dip) ([slides/examples](http://www.slideshare.net/hanekomu/dip-11820640)).